# I want to import an excel file organized as a pivot into a python dataframe where I found 3 columns (Frames, Stringers and Values)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import an excel file organized as a pivot into a python dataframe where I found 3 columns (Frames, Stringers and Values).

Input:
[Input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZQNX.png)

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahyxc.png)

Comment: I think you need to present what you have tried, your research and what's not working in order for us to help you.

Comment: I tried : df1 = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', 'Sheet1', na_values=['NA'])

Comment: but I get as rows the stringers (correct) but for each frame as in the esxcel I get the columns for each frame

Comment: Well that's completely normal, if your data is formatted that way, that's what you will get in while opening it. If you want to change the way you're data is formatted, you will need to do some operations. From what I understand maybe melt can help you : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Else I would suggest splitting into 2 different dfs and then merging them.